# Problem with component destruction in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pusher

I'm building a real time web application that implements a real-time multi-user quiz in which multiple users can participate after choosing a specific role. I am using Vue.js for the front end and pusher.js for real time interaction between the various participants.

The vue.js project consists of 3 components: one for choosing the role, one for the quiz, and one for the quiz results. The single user switch from a component to another thanks to the vue-router when specific conditions are triggered (for example when questions ended, the users are redirected to the results section)

I use pusher events to notify some situations. For example when a user closes the browser window in which the application instance is running, the other participants are notified.This control is based on the "pusher:member_removed" event that is triggered when a user leaves the pusher presence channel. I set up this control in every component, because I pass the channel reference throught the component with the vue-router.

My problem is that the first component (the Home component in which the user choose his role) seems not to be destroyed when the application passes to the quiz component (with the "$router.push()" function). 
Therefore the event triggered when a user closes the browser window with the app in running (and that cause the abandon of the pusher channel) on the quiz component seems to be managed by the first component (the Home component, that should be destroyed).

In fact if I unbound the channel from the "pusher: member_removed" event in the vue "destroyed()" function in the Home component, when the user leaves the application when the route is on the quiz component, the event isn't managed by the "channel.bind" in the quiz component and the other users aren't notified.

This is the definition of the channel (room contains the id of the room in which some users play)

```
  this.channel = ChannelDetails.subscribeToPusher(this.room)
```

This is the binding with the member_removed event that cause the visualization of a banner in the other participants screens (the binding is in all the three components).

```
this.channel.bind('pusher:member_removed', () => {
          this.players -= 1

           $("#myModalDanger").modal({
              show: true
           });
         })
```

How can I resolve this situation?

I tried to unbind the channel from all the events in the vue `destroyed()` function of the `Home` component thinking that this bindings didn't permit the component destruction, but like I said before, with this solution I can't notify the channel abandon of a single user to other participants in the quiz component.

Comment: How are your routes set up? Does your Home component load inside the `<router-view>` component? Or it's the Home component that contains `<router-view>` in its template?

Comment: Sorry @Nilson Jacques, I omitted it. There is an App.vue component that contains the <router-view> tag

Answer (score 0):

In order to run code when the user closes the tab, you'll need to attach a listener to the [`beforeUnload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) event. AFAIK, a component's `destroyed` method is only called when a Vue instance destroys the component.